# Android: SMS is blocked by ChatON app

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, samsung-mobile, smsmanager

I have written an app which receives incoming SMSes, saves it and displays it to the users. Suddenly my app stopped receiving SMS due to Samsung's ChatOn app update.

Here is the my Manifest.xml:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />


 <receiver android:name="com.myapp.sms.service.SMSReceiver"
     android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" android:exported="true">
     <intent-filter android:priority="999">
         <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
     </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

I had this issue earlier with Hangout which started supporting SMS. So, at that time I added priority to 999 (max value) in manifest file. And this worked.

But after recent update of ChatOn app, my app stopped receiving SMS. Please tell me how can I overcome with this.

For work around, I unchecked SMS option on ChatOn app.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, the maximum `android:priority` is not 999. That's what the documentation claims, and the documentation is wrong. The maximum value is whatever the number is for `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, around 2 billion. Bear in mind that even if you request this priority, other apps may still get in ahead of you due to whatever tiebreaker Android uses (GoSMS causes this problem a lot).

Comment: @CommonsWare, Well, if you say documentation is wrong, and if I set priority to Integer.MAX_VALUE, then all other apps will stop receiving the SMS if in case broadcast is stopped by the app. This is what, I guess, ChatOn is doing. This should not be there at all. Then what is correct solution for this? This feature is mandatory for my App.

Comment: "then all other apps will stop receiving the SMS if in case broadcast is stopped by the app" -- an app that aborts an ordered broadcast prevents lower-priority receivers from getting that broadcast. "This is what I guess ChatOn is doing" -- it's a possibility. [Install "App Browser"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.japanesecrackers.appbrowser) and examine ChatOn's manifest. "Then what is correct solution for this?" -- there's nothing you can do if a higher-priority app consumes the event, and you cannot guarantee that you will always be highest priority.

Comment: @CommonsWare, ChatOn app priority is set to 2147483647 and even Hangout has priority as 2147483647. Based on the experience, Hangout doesn't abort broadcast and but looks like ChatOn is aborting broadcast. So, finally I will have to set my app priority to 2147483647.

Answer (score 2):

There is no guaranteed way that your app can get "first crack" at SMS messages, on Android 4.3 and below. Even if you set your app to be the highest possible priority, other apps can do the same. GoSMS notably does this, and you have indicated that ChatOn does as well. If they get the message first and abort the broadcast, you will not receive the message.

There is nothing that you can do, other than to detect this possibility (using `PackageManager`) and alert users as to the potential behavior.

Note that [on Android 4.4, this is a lot different](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html):

- The broadcast can no longer be aborted
- There are separate broadcasts for apps that are monitoring SMS and the actual final SMS client app

Comment: Thanks for your input. I need to support lower versions as well.